# Delete first instance of 0 in a string in a Javascript based on alphanumeric based on certain rules

Tags: javascript

I had a question:

If I had a couple strings like

```
"RZ0214," "T0112," "T1016," "ZZ1011," "10234," "11230"
```

If the first character or second character in the string starts with an alphabet (before the numbers start), if the first number is a 0 that immediately follows the alphabet character(s), I want to remove it from the string.

If the first character in the string starts with a number, if there is a 0 that immediately follows the first numeric character, I want to remove it from the string.

The strings above should eventually look like

```
"RZ214," "T112," "T1016," "ZZ1011," "1234," "11230"
```

Is there any way I can make this happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not without trying probably not no

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty easy to do with [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
str.replace(/^([a-z]+|\d)0/i, '$1')
```

```js
console.log('RZ0214'.replace(/^([a-z]+|\d)0/i, '$1'));
console.log('T1016'.replace(/^([a-z]+|\d)0/i, '$1'));
console.log('10234'.replace(/^([a-z]+|\d)0/i, '$1'));
console.log('11230'.replace(/^([a-z]+|\d)0/i, '$1'));
```

`^([a-z]+|\d)0` only matches if the string starts with one or more letters or a digit, followed by a `0`. In that case, that character sequence is replaced with the letter sequence or the digit, omitting `0`.